# Connection Ethernet MACs without using a PHY device

Tags: ethernet, interface, phy, sgmii

I am designing a board that utilizes an NXP LS1046a processor and multiple Kintex Ultrascale FPGAs. The plan is to connect the processors up to the three FPGAs via the 1Gbe links.
Since they are all on the same board, the plan was to try and connect them up without using any PHY devices, only MAC-MAC communication.

Has anyone ever done this? Do you know if this will work?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: i think that it has been asked here before ... i recall that it is ok to do without magnetics

Comment: @jsotola - I remember a recent question (maybe a few months ago) where the OP was wanting to connect 2 PHYs together without magnetics. But I think this question here is going even further by eliminating the PHYs too.

Comment: There are several standard MAC interfaces : MII for one (at 100Mb/s); and no fundamental reason not to connect two MII interfaces together. Same may or may not be possible at 1Gb/s; read the MAC interface standards.